# FIDO2 (YubiKey) to unlock LUKS from command line

Tags: luks, yubikey

Following the [example](https://0pointer.net/blog/unlocking-luks2-volumes-with-tpm2-fido2-pkcs11-security-hardware-on-systemd-248.html) of how to add a FIDO2 key from a YubiKey, but I can't figure out how to use the YubiKey to unlock it form the command line.  The instructions talk about unlocking at boot--but that's not what I want.

## Setup

Make a 128 MiB file, make it a block device on `loop0` and setup LUKS.

```
$ dd if=/dev/urandom of=disk.bin bs=1M count=128 
128+0 records in
128+0 records out
134217728 bytes (134 MB, 128 MiB) copied, 0.534038 s, 251 MB/s
$ losetup /dev/loop0 disk.bin 
$ cryptsetup luksFormat -y /dev/loop0

WARNING!
========
This will overwrite data on /dev/loop0 irrevocably.

Are you sure? (Type 'yes' in capital letters): YES
Enter passphrase for temp.bin: 
Verify passphrase:
```

Add the Yubikey.

```
$ systemd-cryptenroll /dev/loop0 --fido2-device=auto  --fido2-with-client-pin=yes
 Please enter current passphrase for disk /dev/loop0: ****                    
Requested to lock with PIN, but FIDO2 device /dev/hidraw9 does not support it, disabling.
Initializing FIDO2 credential on security token.
 (Hint: This might require confirmation of user presence on security token.)
Generating secret key on FIDO2 security token.
 In order to allow secret key generation, please confirm presence on security token.
New FIDO2 token enrolled as key slot 1.
```

Remove the the non-FIDO2 key.

```
$ cryptsetup -q -v luksKillSlot /dev/loop0 0
Keyslot 0 is selected for deletion.
Key slot 0 removed.
Command successful.
```

## Problem

Now what?  This doesn't work:

```
$ cryptsetup open /dev/loop0 loop0_encrypted
Enter passphrase for disk.bin:
```

I now have a LUKS disk but I don't know how to unlock it.  All tutorials I found say to make modifications to `/etc/crypttab` and give instructions for mounts at boot.  I want to mount without rebooting and (preferably) without modifying `/etc/crypttab`.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `systemd-cryptenroll` to set up the encryption suggests that you need a similar tool of the `systemd` family to unlock it.

Turns out it is essentially Example 3 in the [systemd-specific version  of the `crypttab(5)` man page.](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/crypttab.html)

```
sudo /usr/lib/systemd/systemd-cryptsetup attach loop0_encrypted /dev/loop0 - fido2-device=auto
```

The equivalent `/etc/crypttab` entry would be:

```
loop0_encrypted /dev/loop0 - fido2-device=auto
```

Note that for example, on Debian 12, the `crypttab(5)` man page says:

> **ON DIFFERENT CRYPTTAB FORMATS**
>
> Please note that there are several independent cryptsetup wrappers with their own `crypttab` format. This manpage covers Debian's implementation for `initramfs` scripts and `SysVinit` init scripts. `systemd` brings its own crypttab implementation. We try to cover the differences between the systemd and our implementation in this manpage, but if in doubt, better check the systemd crypttab(5) manpage, e.g. online at https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/crypttab.html.

Answer (score 1):

When configuring the FIDO2 security token to require a PIN it conflicts with regular LUKS passphrase entry, since both are entered on the host via keyboard. The option `--token-only` is used to indicate that a PIN will be entered, instead of a passphrase, and passed to the (here presumed single) security token.

```bash
sudo cryptsetup open --token-only /dev/loop0 loop0_encrypted
```

Using `--token-only` is simple enough for manual FIDO2+PIN usage, such as when connecting external disks/USB sticks, etcetera. Having `cryptsetup` automatically switch to PIN entry when there are no passphrase slots does sound like a reasonable usability improvement though. (TODO: update answer if default behavior changes.)

---

Tested using [cryptsetup v2.6.1](https://gitlab.com/cryptsetup/cryptsetup/-/tags/v2.6.1) (tagged 2023-02-09); available in Debian 12 (Bookworm), Ubuntu 23.04 (Lunar Lobster), Fedora F38, etcetera.

From the upstream [`cryptsetup open` docs](https://gitlab.com/cryptsetup/cryptsetup/-/blob/v2.6.1/man/cryptsetup-open.8.adoc?ref_type=tags#user-content-luks). (Emphasis mine.)

> If there is valid LUKS2 token but it **requires PIN** to unlock assigned keyslot, it is **not used unless** one of following options is added: **`--token-only`**,
> `--token-type` where `type` matches desired PIN protected token or `--token-id` with `id` matching PIN protected token.

[Debian 12 man page](https://manpages.debian.org/bookworm/cryptsetup-bin/cryptsetup-open.8.en.html). (Emphasis mine.)

> **`--token-only`**
> Do not proceed further with action if token based keyslot unlock failed. Without the option, action asks for passphrase to proceed further.
>
> It allows LUKS2 tokens protected by **PIN to take precedence over interactive keyslot passphrase prompt**.